# Touchpad freezing

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, vaio, alps

I am using a Sony Vaio VPCEB34EN model laptop. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and some time after starting up system my touchpad starts freezing and sometimes it clicks on something which I had never clicked on. Sometimes it doesn't scroll the way the finger movement should make it scroll.

Please help me regarding fixing these issues.

Output of `dmesg | grep pnp`

> [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic root=UUID=253e2121-9e34-4907-b09f-81ce8e4b0706 ro i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop quiet splash vt.handoff=7
>
> [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic root=UUID=253e2121-9e34-4907-b09f-81ce8e4b0706 ro i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop quiet splash vt.handoff=7
>
> [    0.815565] pnp: PnP ACPI init
>   [    0.815627] pnp 00:00: [dma 4]
>   [    0.815652] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
>   [    0.815675] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT0800 (active)
>   [    0.815787] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active)
>   [    0.815823] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active)
>   [    0.815936] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
>   [    0.815962] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
>   [    0.816012] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f13 (active)
>   [    0.838973] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 9 devices

`uname -r` shows `3.13.0-49-generic`

`xinput` gives this output.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Optical USB Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALPS PS/2 Device                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
  ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB 2.0 Camera                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp; uname -r` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to upgrade kernel. You can do it by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

The touchpad should work well after reboot.